# change in the mongoose schema not reflecting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am writing the code using express and mongo db. I am changing my schema time to time but the schema is not able to change at the database level.
For eg:

```
{ id: { type: 'String', required: true },
 name: { type: 'String', required: true, unique: true }
}
```

is changed to

```
{ id: { type: 'String', required: true },
 name: { type: 'String', required: true }
}
```

but my database is using initial schema only until or unless I delete whole collection and then make schema again. I want that the schema of mongoose should change as we are changing the schema on our side without deleting the data.

Comment: You need to actually go and drop the index yourself. Mongoose only "creates indexes", it does not "remove them" when you take them out of your schema. `db.getCollection('<yourCollectionName>').dropIndexes()` should do the trick. Does not remove the collection or any data, but just the indexes. Mongoose will recreate any actual needed ones you still have defined on startup until you tell it not to.

Comment: How can I put this code in my code as the schema keeps on changing and I want that whatever the latest schema is there it should work like that. I am giving a sample code for that.    
    const collectionObject = { collection: modelName, timestamps: true };
    const mongoSchema = new Schema(model, collectionObject);
    const createdModel = mongoose.model(modelName, mongoSchema);

Comment: See you really should not be "relying" on this. Mongoose really only does this "creation" as a "convenience" for developers. If you wan't something more bulletproof you really should design a process to drop all indexes and recreate what you just need as part of your maintenance and also eventual deployment process. See [Indexes](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) in the guide documentation where it is recommended to "turn off auto indexing" once you don't need the training wheels anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is because mongoose has created a unique index automatically when you first define the unique field.

```
db.Admin.dropIndex( { "name" : -1 } )
```

This will drop your index